# How are secret hats during the winter bash earned?

Tags: support

I earned a secret hat today and do not have any idea how I earned it. When I saw others with secret hats, I had the expectation that it would tell me the "secret" if I happened to earn one. This was not the case.

How are secret hats earned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're [not telling people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211707/i-have-a-secret-hat) -- Stack Exchange took their love of secrets to a whole new level this year. I don't really have any idea how you're supposed to deduce what a hat is for, but if you post about a specific one somebody who knows might be able to tell you